# How to edit glyph image icons Swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I am new to swift 4.2, and I was wondering can I edit the glyph-image pin icon in swift 4. For example, instead of the red marker with the pin could it be an as red marker with fast food icon? Thanks for the help.

Here is my code:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

      let identifier = "marker"
      var view: MKMarkerAnnotationView

      if let dequeuedView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier)
        as? MKMarkerAnnotationView {

        dequeuedView.annotation = annotation

        view = dequeuedView
      } else {

        view = MKMarkerAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)

        view.canShowCallout = true

        view.calloutOffset = CGPoint(x: -5, y: 5)
        view.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
      }
      return view
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't *edit* it, but you can certainly *replace* it. Just set the MKMarkerAnnotationView's `glyphImage`.

Comment: Look at the docs for MKMarkerAnnotationView's `glyphImage`. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmarkerannotationview/2873823-glyphimage